# OpenOffice XML document features and corresponding xml element mapping

Tags: openoffice.org

Standard ECMA-376, Office Open XML File Formats
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

It has specification for how a feature in given document (say a word made bold in docx file) corresponds to XML.

These mappings are spread over the specification.

Is there any tabular summary available for mapping a feature in given document type (word, point, excel) to corresponding XML?

E.g.
DOCX features-xml mapping

```
Feature XML

Bold <w:r><w:rPr><w:b/>

Text Border <w:r><w:rPr><w:bdr/>
```

and so on.